# How to handle changes to active automations?

Tags: marketing-automation

We're in the process of standing up the Sitecore CMS 9.1 with `Marketing Automation`, and I've been theorising how we might best handle updating and versioning automation flows. We haven't run them to date, so this is a new paradigm for us.

One approach I had considered was:

- Creating a duplicate of an active journey to amend
- Testing changes in a test environment
- Promoting tested new journey to production

The issue of switching one journey off and switching on another journey not happening simultaneously seems like it could be problematic to me, though. We'd either be having users not be enrolled in any down time, or potentially double-enroll them if I turn on one before turning on another.

To mitigate risk, I had though of abstracting the Start of the automation to a micro-automation that could act as an independent switch.

**For example:**

- Initially, it would simply be: If event occurs, move to Automation A
- Once new journey has been created, update to: If event occurs, move to Automation B

Am I over thinking this and creating unnecessary complexity?

Comment: Great question, my 2c is that the risk of double enrolling contacts is going to be quite high if you start duplicating automation plans to make changes. I like the mitigation for it, but yes that could get very complex very quickly. I'd recommend just testing all changes on the existing plan against contacts who are in various applicable stages of the plan as well as new contacts.